# Mail App's emails button iPhone

Tags: iphone, button

I need a for a project i'm working on a button similar to the one the Mail app use to display the a contacts.

If you don't see what i'm talking about, please see this image: http://www.aboutptc.net/theButtonIneed.png

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mail App's button is an undocumented class.

Nevertheless, you can easily simulate this with a custom stretchable background image, and a UIButton.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where can i find the images to use for that?

Comment: @user: Look in the `MessageUI.framework` folder in the simulator SDK.

Comment: i finaly recreated the image and used a UIButton to simulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code... you need to grab the images from the `MessageUI.framework`:

```
-(UIButton *) buttonForComposeName:(NSString *) name{
    UIButton *button;
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    CGSize stringSize=[name sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, stringSize.width+10, 20)];
    [button setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(composeNameButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"Compose_atom@2x.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:25 topCapHeight:0];
    image=[MailRect imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(button.frame.size.width*2, 40)];

    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(void) composeNameButtonTapped:(id)sender{
    ((UIButton *)sender).selected=YES;

    UIImage *imageSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"compose_atom_selected@2x.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:25 topCapHeight:0];
    imageSelected=[MailRect imageWithImage:imageSelected scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(((UIButton *)sender).frame.size.width*2, 40)];

    [((UIButton *)sender) setBackgroundImage:imageSelected forState:(UIControlStateSelected)];
}

+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```