# How to open MessageUI.framework to grab the images used in it

Tags: iphone, frameworks

I am trying to access the Mail App's emails button (iPhone [Mail App's emails button iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370721/mail-apps-emails-button-iphone)). Please see the comments in the link. I need to open the contents of that folder to access the image. Please. let me know how to open. All i see them are as executable files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator<LatestVersion>.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/`, there should be a lot of PNG files. You may need to [decode those PNG images](http://www.newsfirex.com/blog/?p=176) to see them on the computer.